# Is there any way to check if the emails sent by my app are open?

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ses

Hello I have developed an application that works with React.js and Node.js.

I use AWS and SES (Simple Email Service) to send some emails.

My question is whether there is any way I can keep track of emails sent and opened by my users to prevent them from qualifying me as spam or that my SES account health will decrease too much.

I have seen that there are some browser extensions with which it marks the emails sent with a double tick if the user have read it, but I do not have a record such as in gmail.

Has anyone encountered any similar problems?
Is it possible via AWS or via Node to achieve this?

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with @Ravi's answer above - SES does [provide notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/dg/monitor-sending-activity-using-notifications.html) - however in my experience the open notification is a lot less reliable than the delivered and bounce notifications.

Tracking opens is difficult as browsers, popup blockers/security software and email clients themselves can disable/break features like read-receipts and tracking pixels in the name or privacy. The most reliable way of tracking opens is to have a clickable link in the email body (and a compelling reason for your user to click on it) and include a unique id in the URL that you can capture server-side.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of some simple configurations with SES and SNS. By creating a topic and doing the subscription like where you want to get the notifications. Through this, you can track the status of your emails whether they are opened or not. SNS will send you email notifications.